# redshift array_to_string does not work with union

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-redshift, union

I am attempting to run array_to_string with a union in redshift but i keep getting the following error message:

```
ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables. [SQL State=0A000]
```

The query itself is pretty straight forward, so i am not sure why i keep getting this, can someone please advise

```
(SELECT array_to_string(array(select column_name::text from information_schema.columns where table_name= 'customer_insert' order by ordinal_position),'|'))
UNION 
(select "user.firstname"::text from digital.customer_insert where "user.isocountrycode" = 'BE' limit 2)
```

Comment: Amazon Redshift is not exactly Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Redshift does not support Postgres's Array type:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html